# Find middle date for each observation given year, month, and week number of the month

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I have date data in three columns that looks like this:

| Year | Month | Week |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | April | 1 |
| 2019 | April | 2 |
| 2019 | April | 3 |
| 2019 | April | 4 |
| 2019 | May | 1 |
| 2019 | May | 2 |
| 2019 | May | 3 |
| 2019 | May | 4 |

Where 'week' corresponds to the week position (1-4) of the month. What I would like to have is the calculate the middle date for that corresponding date. For example, for the first row (2019, April, and week 1) this corresponds to April 1st 2019 - April 6th 2019, so I would like ideally a column of the midpoint of this week, so that would (roughly) be April 3rd or 4th 2019. Exact date is not necessary.

So the ending table should look like this:

| Year | Month | Week | Midpoint |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | April | 1 | 2019-04-03 |

Here is some example data:

```
structure(list(Month = c("May", "May", "August", "April", "May", 
"May", "July", "August", "July", "May", "July", "May", "July", 
"April", "May", "July", "May", "April", "August", "July"), Week = c("wk 4", 
"wk 4", "wk 2", "wk 4", "wk 4", "wk 5", "wk 4", "wk 2", "wk 3", 
"wk 4", "wk 1", "wk 3", "wk 3", "wk 3", "wk 2", "wk 3", "wk 5", 
"wk 4", "wk 3", "wk 1"), Year = c("2016", "2007", "2010", "1991", 
"2012", "1990", "2011", "2014", "2020", "2011", "2010", "1992", 
"2017", "2020", "2014", "1996", "2012", "1995", "2018", "2019"
)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: Do weeks always begin on Monday and go through Sunday, or do they begin on the 1st of the month and go through 7 days?  For example, which of the following is the last day of the first week of this July: Sunday 7/4 or Wednesday 7/7?  Also, what should we do for February on a leap year, if the 29th is the start of a new week?  In that case, the 4th week would only contain a single day before the end of the month, and there would be no "middle date" for the 4th week of February.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function to find the midpoint as follows (`my_df` if your sample data):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# <-- Function to find midpoint of week -->
midweek <- \(year, month, month_week) {
  # first day of the month
  date <- paste(year, month, "1st") |> lubridate::ymd()
  
  # return middle date of the month week
  date + 7 * month_week - 4
}


my_df |> mutate(
  Week = gsub("wk ", "", Week) |> as.integer(), 
  midpoint = midweek(Year, Month, Week)
)
```

```
#> # A tibble: 20 x 4
#>    Month   Week Year  midpoint  
#>    <chr>  <int> <chr> <date>    
#>  1 May        4 2016  2016-05-25
#>  2 May        4 2007  2007-05-25
#>  3 August     2 2010  2010-08-11
#>  4 April      4 1991  1991-04-25
#>  5 May        4 2012  2012-05-25
#>  6 May        5 1990  1990-06-01
#>  7 July       4 2011  2011-07-25
#>  8 August     2 2014  2014-08-11
#>  9 July       3 2020  2020-07-18
#> 10 May        4 2011  2011-05-25
#> 11 July       1 2010  2010-07-04
#> 12 May        3 1992  1992-05-18
#> 13 July       3 2017  2017-07-18
#> 14 April      3 2020  2020-04-18
#> 15 May        2 2014  2014-05-11
#> 16 July       3 1996  1996-07-18
#> 17 May        5 2012  2012-06-01
#> 18 April      4 1995  1995-04-25
#> 19 August     3 2018  2018-08-18
#> 20 July       1 2019  2019-07-04
```

Comment: This is a interesting approach, but note that some dates will be carried over to the following week or month, such as id: 6 `6 May        5 1990  1990-06-01`.

Comment: `Where 'week' corresponds to the week position (1-4) of the month`, where is 5 coming from?

Comment: there can be up to 6 weeks within a month when the first day of the month starts late in the week. I believe the OP didn't think of that when formulating the question. Apart from Februaries, there are always at least 5 weeks within a month.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do it. It is very hacky though.

```
shift_to_middle_of_week <- function(Year, Month, Week) {
  
  Week = str_extract(Week, "\\d+") %>% as.numeric()
  date_first_week = (paste(Year, Month, "1", sep = "-")) %>% ymd()
  dow = wday(date_first_week)
  
  week_start = if_else(
    Week == 1, 
    date_first_week, 
    date_first_week + ((Week-1)*7)-dow+1
  ) 
  
  shift = floor((7-dow)/2)
  
  ceil = ceiling_date(date_first_week, unit = "month")-1
  diff_ceil_week_start = ceil - week_start
  
  shift = if_else(diff_ceil_week_start<6, 
                  floor(diff_ceil_week_start/2), 
                  shift)
  return(week_start + shift)
}

df %>% 
  mutate(
    date_mid_week = shift_to_middle_of_week(Year, Month, Week)
  )
#> # A tibble: 20 x 4
#>    Month  Week  Year  date_mid_week
#>    <chr>  <chr> <chr> <date>       
#>  1 May    wk 4  2016  2016-05-25   
#>  2 May    wk 4  2007  2007-05-22   
#>  3 August wk 2  2010  2010-08-11   
#>  4 April  wk 4  1991  1991-04-23   
#>  5 May    wk 4  2012  2012-05-22   
#>  6 May    wk 5  1990  1990-05-29   
#>  7 July   wk 4  2011  2011-07-17   
#>  8 August wk 2  2014  2014-08-03   
#>  9 July   wk 3  2020  2020-07-13   
#> 10 May    wk 4  2011  2011-05-25   
#> 11 July   wk 1  2010  2010-07-02   
#> 12 May    wk 3  1992  1992-05-10   
#> 13 July   wk 3  2017  2017-07-09   
#> 14 April  wk 3  2020  2020-04-13   
#> 15 May    wk 2  2014  2014-05-05   
#> 16 July   wk 3  1996  1996-07-16   
#> 17 May    wk 5  2012  2012-05-29   
#> 18 April  wk 4  1995  1995-04-16   
#> 19 August wk 3  2018  2018-08-13   
#> 20 July   wk 1  2019  2019-07-03
```

#### more detail.

Putting everything within a `mutate()` to see the intermediate steps:

```
df %>% mutate(
  Week = str_extract(Week, "\\d+") %>% as.numeric(),
  date_first_week = (paste(Year, Month, "01", sep = "-")) %>% ymd(), 
  dow = wday(date_first_week),
  week_start = if_else(
    Week == 1, 
    date_first_week, 
    date_first_week + ((Week-1)*7)-dow+1
  ), 
  week_start_2 = date_first_week + ((Week-1)*7)-dow+1,

  shift = floor((7-dow)/2),
  ceil = ceiling_date(date_first_week, unit = "month")-1, 
  diff_ceil_week_start = ceil - week_start,
  shift = if_else(diff_ceil_week_start<6, 
                  floor(diff_ceil_week_start/2), 
                  shift), 
  week_mid = week_start + shift
)

# A tibble: 20 x 11
   Month   Week Year  date_first_week   dow week_start week_start_2 shift  ceil       diff_ceil_week_start week_mid  
   <chr>  <dbl> <chr> <date>          <dbl> <date>     <date>       <drtn> <date>     <drtn>               <date>    
 1 May        4 2016  2016-05-01          1 2016-05-22 2016-05-22   3 days 2016-05-31  9 days              2016-05-25
 2 May        4 2007  2007-05-01          3 2007-05-20 2007-05-20   2 days 2007-05-31 11 days              2007-05-22
 3 August     2 2010  2010-08-01          1 2010-08-08 2010-08-08   3 days 2010-08-31 23 days              2010-08-11
 4 April      4 1991  1991-04-01          2 1991-04-21 1991-04-21   2 days 1991-04-30  9 days              1991-04-23
 5 May        4 2012  2012-05-01          3 2012-05-20 2012-05-20   2 days 2012-05-31 11 days              2012-05-22
 6 May        5 1990  1990-05-01          3 1990-05-27 1990-05-27   2 days 1990-05-31  4 days              1990-05-29
 7 July       4 2011  2011-07-01          6 2011-07-17 2011-07-17   0 days 2011-07-31 14 days              2011-07-17
 8 August     2 2014  2014-08-01          6 2014-08-03 2014-08-03   0 days 2014-08-31 28 days              2014-08-03
 9 July       3 2020  2020-07-01          4 2020-07-12 2020-07-12   1 days 2020-07-31 19 days              2020-07-13
10 May        4 2011  2011-05-01          1 2011-05-22 2011-05-22   3 days 2011-05-31  9 days              2011-05-25
11 July       1 2010  2010-07-01          5 2010-07-01 2010-06-27   1 days 2010-07-31 30 days              2010-07-02
12 May        3 1992  1992-05-01          6 1992-05-10 1992-05-10   0 days 1992-05-31 21 days              1992-05-10
13 July       3 2017  2017-07-01          7 2017-07-09 2017-07-09   0 days 2017-07-31 22 days              2017-07-09
14 April      3 2020  2020-04-01          4 2020-04-12 2020-04-12   1 days 2020-04-30 18 days              2020-04-13
15 May        2 2014  2014-05-01          5 2014-05-04 2014-05-04   1 days 2014-05-31 27 days              2014-05-05
16 July       3 1996  1996-07-01          2 1996-07-14 1996-07-14   2 days 1996-07-31 17 days              1996-07-16
17 May        5 2012  2012-05-01          3 2012-05-27 2012-05-27   2 days 2012-05-31  4 days              2012-05-29
18 April      4 1995  1995-04-01          7 1995-04-16 1995-04-16   0 days 1995-04-30 14 days              1995-04-16
19 August     3 2018  2018-08-01          4 2018-08-12 2018-08-12   1 days 2018-08-31 19 days              2018-08-13
20 July       1 2019  2019-07-01          2 2019-07-01 2019-06-30   2 days 2019-07-31 30 days              2019-07-03
```